# How to spindown external drive on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: systemd, external-hdd, spindown

I have an external Seagate Backup plus hard-drive that gets automatically mounted on system boot, however the hard-drive does not get automatically spundown/powerdown with the system is shutdown. I would like to know how to have the hard-drive automatically spundown on system shutdown?

If I use the GUI to power off the drive in Disks application, the hard-drive powers off, and I can shutdown with the drive off. So far I have created a shell script that can power off the drive:

```
#!/bin/sh

a=`lsblk -rno label,name | awk '$1=="Archive"{print $2}'`
sudo umount /media/spacemanngaf/Archive
udisksctl power-off --block-device /dev/${a%?}
```

When I execute this script in a terminal, the drive powers down as required.

I have then tried to setup a systemd service to run the script before system shutdown:

```
[Unit]
Description=HDD backup-plus spin-down at shutdown service
DefaultDependencies=no
RequiresMountsFor=/media/spacemanngaf/Archive
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=True
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/home/spacemanngaf/.hdd_spindown

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, this does not work when I shutdown the system. The service is enabled. How do I get the service to run, or perhaps there is a better way to power down the drive on system shutdown?

Thank you

Comment: Your script uses `sudo`, so it is normally run from your current user in terminal while testing. Specify that user in a `User=...` line in the `[Service]` section. I would recommend putting also `StandardOutput=syslog` and 
`StandardError=syslog` lines in the `[Service]` section and watching for any unexpected errors in `syslog`.

Comment: Thanks. However, this does not work. I must note the service unit file is not marked as allow to execute as program.

Answer (score 0):

Put the script you made earlier into this directory
/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/

It runs everything in that directory before shutdown.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this, but it also does not work. Funny thing about the script, is that it can only be run once, when I test it. If I remount the drive to test a second time, the script runs, but the drive powers off, then powers on without mounting the drive.